# My Elixir recursive function returns a list of lists, not a simple list

Tags: elixir

I am **[learning Elixir](https://pragprog.com/book/elixir12/programming-elixir-1-2)** and according to the linked book (page 64), the following function:

```
defmodule MyList do
  def square([]), do: []
  def square([ head | tail ]), do: [ head*head, square(tail) ]
end
```

should behave as follows:

```
MyList.square [4, 5, 6]
[16, 25, 36]
```

But when I plug it into my Elixir 1.2.0 installation on Ubuntu I get:

```
MyList.square [4, 5, 6]
[16, [25, [36, []]]]
```

What's happening here? Am I wrong or is the book wrong?

How do I get to the simple [16, 25, 36] ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a small error in this line:

```
 def square([ head | tail ]), do: [ head*head, square(tail) ]
```

If we recurse at each step then the output is:

```
square([4, 5, 6])
[16, square([5, 6])]
[16, [25, square([6])]]
[16, [25, [36, square([])]]]
[16, [25, [36, []]]]
```

You want:

```
 def square([ head | tail ]), do: [ head*head | square(tail) ]
```

If we recurse at each step then the output is:

```
square([4, 5, 6])
[16 | square([5, 6])]
[16 | [25 | square([6])]]
[16 | [25 | [36 | square([])]]]
[16 | [25 | [36 | []]]]
```

Trying this in iex gives:

```
iex(3)> [16 | [25 | [36 | []]]]    
[16, 25, 36]
```

Comment: oh brother - silly little syntax error. All makes sense now.

BTW if I may add the speed with which I have received an answer to my (clearly silly) question reminds me of when I first learned Python - before it was fashionable - when the community was really responsive. Very excited about Elixir!

Comment: If you want to get more in touch with the community be sure to check the Elixir channel in Slack and the new Elixir forum (http://elixirforum.com/) :)